# RESTful application without web.xml

Tags: web-services, rest, ejb-3.1

I have created a sample project and used EJB 3.1 with a RESTful web service. In the sample I have a class which extends `Application`. I expect the class works like a servlet and dispatch requests to appropriate classes but it does not. When I use `web.xml` my sample project works fine. What is wrong with my sample project?

```java
@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class ApplicationServlet extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        classes.add(UserWS.class);
        return classes;
    }
}
```

I use `UserWS` as a EJB session bean which exposes web service:

```java
@Stateless
@LocalBean
@Path("/user")
public class UserWS {

    private int count;

    public UserWS() {
        this.count=0;
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/name/{username}")
    public void getUserName(@PathParam("username") String username) {
        count++;
        System.out.println("count is:"+ count);
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the contents of your *web.xml* when you're trying to call your REST service?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
</web-app>

Comment: It's a quite simple *web.xml* :) How are you invoking your REST service?

Comment: What server are you using?

Comment: I am using jboss v5.0

Comment: AFAIK, JBoss 5 does NOT support **Servlet 3.x**, by default. I think it supports **Servlet 2.5**. Hence, you'll need the `web.xml`

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid it won't be possible once JBoss 5.0 supports only **Servlet 2.5**. For more details, see [here](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/VersionOfTomcatInJBossAS).

To avoid the `web.xml` deployment descriptor, you need a servlet container the supports at least **Servlet 3.0**.

---

So, what could you do to solve it?

These are the options that came up to my mind:

1. You could try upgrading the JBoss Web (Tomcat fork used by JBoss AS) as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1841404/1426227), but *try that at you own risk*.
2. Consider using a recent version of JBoss/WildFly.

Comment: thank you! i have changed application server and updated it to WildFly 10 as well JDK to 1.8. My sample project works fine now without web.xml!